# Jscroll pane is not working when dynamic data is appended to an empty div

Tags: jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have an empty div to which data may be appended dynamically through a ajax call on button click. I have Jscroll pane tagged to that div and its not working. The div is without scroll. But the scroll works when I put only a static data to that div. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialize the scrollbar whenever the content is updated. See an example here http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html